# SQL Query to itemized Daily Sales Per Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my Sales Table, listed is the daily sales of particular tenant in one Property.

**Using this code**, I was able to list or select daily Sales of tenants, summed up based on grouping of Property.

```
SELECT  date , location ,  SUM(a.gsc) Sales
FROM  SalesTable
WHERE (date  BETWEEN  '01/01/2015'   AND '12/31/2015' ) 
      and (location  = 'Property1')
GROUP BY location ,  date
ORDER BY location, date
```

**And the result is something like this**

```
Date         Location     Sales
01/01/2015   Property1    10,000
01/02/2015   Property1    20,000
.
.
.
12/31/2015   Property1    15,000
```

What I wish to accomplish as the final output is make the result in tabular form having Days date as the first Row and Month as the columns. ***Please see sample output for further illustration.***

```
Date  January              February               
      Date   Day  Sales    Date    Day  Sales
1     1-Jan  Fri  10,000   1-Feb   Mon  9,000
2     2-Jan  Sat  20,000   2-Feb   Tue  10,000
3     .      .    .        .       .    .
4     .      .    .        .       .    .
5     .      .    .        .       .    .
6    
7
8
.
.
.
.
.
31
```

**This is what I tried**

```
 SELECT  date , location ,  SUM(a.gsc) Sales
 INTO #TempTable1
 FROM  SalesTable
 WHERE (date  BETWEEN  '01/01/2015'   AND '12/31/2015' ) 
          and (location  = 'Property1')
 GROUP BY location ,  date
 ORDER BY location, date



    SELECT   months.number, tenants.locationd   ,  tenants.location       
        ,(case when (t.DATE) = 1  then t.gsc end) as 'January'
        ,(case when (t.DATE) = 2 then t.gsc end)) as 'February'
        (case when year(t.DATE) = 3 then t.gsc end) as 'March'

         FROM 
            (       
                    SELECT Number 
                    FROM master..spt_values 
                    WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and 31
            ) months
            CROSS JOIN
            (       --12 Month Name will be cross joined sa selected tenant/s
                    SELECT DISTINCT  locationd ,  location
                    FROM #AMRDSR1
            ) tenants    

    LEFT JOIN #AMRDSR1 t   
     ON months.number = datepart(day,t.date) and tenants.location = t.location 
    GROUP BY  months.number, tenants.locationd  , tenants.location , t.date, t.gsc 
    ORDER BY  tenants.locationd ,  datepart(day,t.date)
```

I have been suggested to used pivot, but that is quite new to me and seemed to be very complicated, If there are ways to do it just using TSQL, much better.

Hoping for your expert advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- assuming you only show one year of data at a time

; with 
-- first get sales by date and the day of month and also month etc.
data
(
  SELECT [date] , SUM(a.gsc) AS Sales,
         datepart(day, [date]) as [Day],
         datepart(month, [date]) as [Month],
         left(datename(weekday, [date]),3) as [WeekDay]
  FROM   SalesTable a
  WHERE  ([date]  BETWEEN  '01/01/2015'   AND '12/31/2015' ) 
  and    (location  = 'Property1')
  GROUP BY [date]
)
-- Now the "pivoting" using CASE WHEN .... with aggregate function
SELECT [Day],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 THEN [date] END) as Date_Jan,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 THEN [WeekDay] END) as WeekDay_Jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 THEN [Sales] END) as Sales_Jan,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = 2 THEN [date] END) as Date_Feb,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = 2 THEN [WeekDay] END) as WeekDay_Feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 2 THEN [Sales] END) as Sales_Feb,
       . . . .
FROM   data
GROUP BY [Day]
```